# Newton Polytopes of Tropical Polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polytopes, tropical-geometry, convex-hulls

recently I've been reading about tropical polynomials and stumbled upon Andreas Gathmann's [lecture notes](http://tenchi.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/pub/trop-0601322.pdf).

In section 1.4, it is stated that a tropical polynomial in the form of

$$  g(x, y) = \max_i \{a_1^{(i)} x + a_2^{(i)} y \}  $$

as a function depends on only the points $ (a_1^{(i)}, a_2^{(i)} )$ that are vertices of its Newton polygon $ \text{Newt}(g) = \text{conv}\{ (a_1^{(i)}, a_2^{(i)}) \} $

I can understand that this also generalizes to newton polytopes in higher dimensions, since all interior points will satisfy $ \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} < \mathbf{a}_{k}^T \mathbf{x} $, where $\mathbf{a}_k$ is a vertex of the Newton Polytope.

What happens if $g$ also includes constant terms in its factors? E.g. if

$$ g(x, y) = \max_i \{ a_1^{(i)} x +  a_2^{(i)} y + b_i \} $$

Can we incorporate in some way the constant terms in the Newton polytope construction to extend the above statement concerning the interior points?

Comment: Cannot you construct the corresponding Newton polytope (say, $P$) for the function $G(x,y,z)=\max_i \{ a_1^{(i)} x +  a_2^{(i)} y + b_i z \} $, and then take those pairs $(a_1^i, a_2^i)$ that correspond to vertices $(a_1^i, a_2^i,b_i)$ of $P$? I think this works because if your $g(x,y)$ can have a maximum with some $i$ then $G(x,y,z)$ can also have a maximum with the same $i$, so this $i$ corresponds to a vertex of $P$.